# Why ES6 function wont output data from node view

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use ES6 function to output data from NODE view.

route.js

```
res.render("../modules/users/views/userList", {
            iAmOutput: "LOL",
        });
```

Handlebars

```
 <script type="text/javascript">console.log(`${iAmOutput}`);</script>
```

but console still saying "`show:99 Uncaught ReferenceError: iAmOutput is not defined`"

I will be thankful for any idea.

Comment: try `console.log(<%= iAmOutput %>)`

Comment: @Sergey Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: Handlebars use…well handlebars…for interpolation: `{{iAmOutput}}`

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah i know this but i want to do this without {{iAmOutput}} just with javascript

Comment: The browser won't have access to the variable `iAmOutput` the interpolation is done on the server when it builds the page.

Comment: try that 
`var anyName = iAmOutput` and then `console.log(anyName)`

Comment: Why won't you use handlebars?

Comment: @MarkMeyer and is there any way how can i do this with pure javascript?

Comment: @Sergey Because nobody is answering handlebars questions and i dont know how to put any from handlebars into javascript function.
Like <script> nothing = {{something}} </script> wont work

Comment: You need to somehow get the value written into the page when the template is rendered. You could set the variable in the script: `<script type="text/javascript">let iAmOutput = {{iAmOutput}}; console.log(\`${iAmOutput}\`);</script>`

Comment: Thank guys it works :D i was just missing variable...